# Is there a way to connect to a H2 database from Ruby without JRuby?

Tags: ruby, database-connection, jruby, watir, h2

I'm testing a web application with ruby 1.8.7 and WATiR and I'd like to connect to a H2 database as easily as possible, which I can only find info on JDBC access for. If there's a way to use JRuby to do this from Ruby that is okay, but I need to use Ruby primarily because my WATiR code is written in it and will hopefully remain so.

All possible solutions will be considered but I'm looking for some simplicity because my database knowledge is limited and I need to access the database (read from and write to) from Ruby/WATiR to test against what's displayed on the web front end.

EDIT: I removed some of my ignorance, now I know JDBC is a Java API for DB access, so I'm now looking for any way to connect to a H2 database so that my Ruby/WATiR scripts can access it.

**Background**:
I have some experience with DBI and Sequel gems, and I have Rails installed (so I can start to play with ActiveRecord, mainly), but willing to learn new things to solve this issue.

Let's assume I'm not a great Java coder. I've also never looked into using JRuby before, so I'm not entirely familiar with how it works.

**Solution**
I eventually got the two talking to each other, mainly thanks to Thomas Mueller's answer below. I installed the PostgreSQL ODBC driver, got Sequel working and connected using ODBC. Using Sequel's PG adapter to connect to the H2 PG server causes some Syntax errors that I'm still working on. I have not yet tried DBI to connect, but I will as it may give me greater control of the syntax should I need it. Many thanks also to Jeremy Evans for his help solving a conflict between activerecord-jdbc-adapter and Sequel (pesky pg.rb file in my ruby path), and for managing Sequel. This is not listed as an answer so that I can give credit to those that answered whilst giving feedback to people in the same situation as me.

I have installed pg (not ruby-pg), sequel, dbi, dbd-odbc (plus a manual file fix, you can ask me for details), hoe, and UNinstalled activerecord-jdbc-adapter.

Comment: Thanks for the followup and wrapup of your solution.  That should be of great benefit to other users in the same situation as you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[H2 can act as a PostgreSQL server and supports the PostgreSQL ODBC driver](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#odbc_driver).

So in theory you should be able to use [ruby-pg](http://rubyforge.org/projects/ruby-pg). But I have never tried it myself, I guess the chances that it works are about 50%. So the answer is: maybe. But the preferred solution is to use JRuby.

If WATiR is written in Ruby... [then WATiR should also work in JRuby](http://developer-in-test.blogspot.com/2009/03/jwatir-watir-on-jruby-experiment.html)?

Answer (score 2):

there is no such thing named **jdbc database**, you can access any database using ruby so long as the database provides a ruby connector.

Comment: Aha, so the question I should be asking is how to connect to a H2 database from Ruby. My brain thanks you.

Comment: I am not familiar with H2, but have a look at this link: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/107819

Answer (score 2):

IMHO your two best options are either the DBI or Sequel gems.

The DBI gem can be used to connect to a db via ODBC.  If H2 has an ability as Thomas indicates to support ODBC then you should be able to use DBI to connect to and query the db (which of course includes 'update' queries to setup given test data etc).

See the rubyforge [DBI Page](http://ruby-dbi.rubyforge.org/) for more info.  DBI has been around a while so it's fairly easy to find online tutorials for how to use it, etc. It is fairly low level, and you need to know SQL or your DB's language, in order to interact well with it.

Another option would be the SEQUEL gem, which has an option to connect via ODBC or JDBC (JDBC has a H2 sub-adaptor).  This Gem is newer and offers some specific advantages over DBI.   see this link to the [Opening_Databases](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/opening_databases_rdoc.html) portion of the rdoc files for Sequel where it talks a little bit about using JDBC to connect to databases.  I guess which is easier depends on how hard the ODBC is to setup for H2  vs how much Java you have to learn in order to get JDBC working for you.  (I'd head for ODBC first if it was me, since I know very little Java)

Myself, I've been using DBI so far (to connect to MS SQL via ODBC), but I have to admit wondering if using the Sequel gem instead might be better.  Sequel saves you from writing a lot of actual SQL type code or even having to understand SQL queries in depth, and lets you do everything ruby style using methods, symbols and some strings here and there.  If you are doing a LOT of db interaction I can see where it is clearly superior especially in terms of being able to create a lot more pure OOP code.  See [this presentation](http://jeremyevans-pres.heroku.com/rk2009_presentation/sequel-rubykaigi2009.html) by the Sequel author at a Ruby conference in 2009 for more details.

In my case DBI is 'good enough' for what I need since I am very comfortable with SQL, and don't really need to do much other than issue a few commands here and there to do db-level bit-twiddling to create proper test conditions.   OTOH if I was having to do a lot of queries against the db as a test oracle and comparing that with data presented in the UI, I can see where using Sequel would make my life a lot easier.

Comment: I've been using DBI to access an ODBC for MSSQL so far. Sequel would be a nice addition, but I find every time I run it I get "no such file to load -- java" (Sequel::AdapterNotFound). This is probably due to some obscure file I need to copy to some directory or other, but I'm going for DBI and ODBC via PostgreSQL as per TM's suggestion. If I can get ODBC to work for H2 then all my problems are over. I will update with my findings. Thanks for your suggestions :)

Comment: You can only use Sequel's jdbc adapter if you are using JRuby, which is why you get the "no such file to load -- java" error.

Comment: @Jeremy This is true. JDBC and Ruby do not like each other. I have now used Sequel to connect using ODBC, it works just fine. Just for the record :).

Comment: @kinofrost Glad to hear that my pointing you at the Sequel gem helped you find a solution.

Comment: In a way, yes. I already knew about the sequel gem, but I had to fix an error in it to make it work. It was the PostgreSQL ODBC driver that saved my skin, but I'd still need to use JRuby if I wanted to have full connection functionality. The PG in Sequel doesn't talk to H2, there is some kind of syntactical dissonance going on.